# Error al intentar conectarse al sql plus desde la terminal de Ubuntu

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy intentando conectarme al sql plus desde ubuntu pero me sale este ERROR

```
ubuntu@ubuntu6:~$ su oracle
Contraseña: 
oracle@ubuntu6:/home/ubuntu$ lsnrctl start
oracle@ubuntu6:/home/ubuntu$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 5 17:39:09 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 ERROR:
 ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener mucho conocimiento de Oracle, te diría que miraras el archivo listener.ora o el tnsnames.ora de Oracle y revisaría la configuración de estos ficheros.

Comment: Bienvenido a [se] Jaime. Considera en lugar de dar una respuesta, comentar la post del OP. Las respuestas deben ser concisas y si el OP no ofrece toda la información, dejarle un comentario es la mejor opción.

Comment: Muchas gracias David, lo tengo en cuenta para la siguiente ocasión.